# How to generate and add an instance method to a class in runtime but compiling a method only once?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to implement a mixin that adds some method to a instance that mangles name of base class's specific field name.

Code looks something like this

```
class TimeSeriesObjectRetrieverMixin(object):
"""Time Series Object Retriever Mixin.

Offers reverse related object retrieval methods to mixed in model where the
reverse relation contains time related fields(DateField, DateTimeField).
"""
# TODO: SERIOUS PERFORMANCE BOTTLENECK DUE TO FUNCTION CODE COMPILATION FOR EVERY
#       INSTANTIATION. FIX THIS.
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self._n = {}

    for time_series_object_name, time_series_field_name in self.time_series:
        time_series_object = getattr(self, time_series_object_name)
        time_series_field = time_series_object.model._meta.get_field(time_series_field_name)

        # Time series field has to be one of DateField or DateTimeField.
        assert(isinstance(time_series_field, DateField) or
               isinstance(time_series_field, DateTimeField))

        self._add_get_in_last_delta(time_series_object_name,
                                    time_series_field_name)

 def time_series(self):
    """
    Time Series Property.

    You must implement this property in your base class to mix this
    mixin into your model.

    Example:
            time_seires =
            [
                ('reverse_related_object_name', 'created_time'),
                ('votes', 'time'),
                ('cash_flow_rate', 'time'),
            ]
    """
    return super(TimeSeriesObjectRetrieverMixin, self).time_series
```

So this mixin will add ***get_in_last_delta*** method for every instantiated objects.

But this causes a lot of overhead since the compilation is processed for every object instantiation (***_add_get_in_last_delta*** is implemented with ***exec*** and ***compile***).

Is there any nice way to add an runtime generated instance method to a class in program's first class definition rather than class instantiation?

---

*_add_get_in_last_delta() :*

```
def _add_method(self, fn):
    from types import MethodType
    setattr(self, fn, MethodType(self._n[fn], self))

def _add_get_in_last_delta(self,
                           time_series_object_name,
                           time_series_field_name):
    # Generate a function name.
    fn = 'get_{}_in_last_delta'.format(time_series_object_name)

    # Generate a name mangled function code.
    exec compile((
        'from django.utils import timezone\n'
        'def {}(self, delta):\n'
        '   return self.{}.filter({}__gte=(timezone.now()-delta))').
        format(fn, time_series_object_name, time_series_field_name),
        '<string>', 'exec') in self._n

    # Bind the method to the instance.
    self._add_method(fn)
```

---

*p.s. I'm trying this in django to mixin this class to my model.*

Comment: Usually the way a mixin works is you define the methods in it, then inherit from it (along with other classes --- that is, you "mix it in" with other classes in the inheritance hierarchy).  Then the methods will be available on instances of the "mixed" class.  Why are you adding the method to individual instances at all?

Comment: What I want is **to add runtime generated, name mangled instance method depending on base class's specific field's name**, which will be explicitly defined in base class (i.e. Implementing `time_series` in base class in case of the above code).

Comment: You didn't answer the question. *Why* do you want to do this?

Comment: I don't get what you are asking for.. Am I missing something? I'm adding the method to instances eventually to use them on the template side(I know they are taking arguments, but by making thin wrapper function or something).

Comment: The method's purpose is to return a time series of reverse related object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any need for that compile code. Everything you're doing in the dynamically-defined function can be done via normal Python.

```
from django.utils import timezone
from types import MethodType

def _add_get_in_last_delta(self,
                           time_series_object_name,
                           time_series_field_name):
    # Generate a function name.
    fn = 'get_{}_in_last_delta'.format(time_series_object_name)

    def dynamic_method(self, delta, obj=time_series_object_name, field=time_series_field_name):
        return getattr(self, time_series_object_name).filter(
            **{'{}__gte'.format(time_series_field_name): timezone.now()-delta})

    # Bind the method to the instance.
    setattr(self, fn, MethodType(dynamic_method, self))
```

The function will still be executed for every instantiation, but the inner func is only compiled once at first import. (The object/field names are provided via default kwargs, because of the way [Python closures work](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures), but they can safely be ignored by anyone calling the resulting method.)